# ignore error and search for the next element

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

I am reading a text from a page. But sometimes the searching element is missing. So, I would like to continue the searching with the next page. Is possible to jump the non-existing element and continue to the next page.

This is my code:

```
while True:
    try:
        address = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"page\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span[3]/span[1]/span")   
    except:
        print("bad page:")
```

this is the error:

```
Unable to locate element:  {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="page"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span[3]/span[1]/span"}
```

thanks!

Comment: You have already handled the error, your loop should continue as is. What is the problem?

Comment: @MohitC i get the error everytime when the element is missing on the page

Comment: And I see that you have already handled that error so not able to understand what is the problem here. You need to post more (minimal) code to reproduce the problem

Comment: @MohitC i am using googlechrome driver with selenium to read a text from a page. But this pages are not equal. Sometimes, there are missing searching elements on the page. When it comes to the missing element the loop is broken and i get this error.

Comment: You can catch it in a "Try/Catch" and ignore it if you must.  Not very advisable to do that, but if that's what you want to do, you could very possibly do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Python - Handling No such element exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022658/selenium-python-handling-no-such-element-exception)

Answer (score 0):

## Ignoring No such element Error and execute next statement

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    address = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"page\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span[3]/span[1]/span")  
   
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("element not available")
    pass
```