# How can I check if a web element exists using selenium and then do an if then statement if it does exist?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, element

I'm pretty much brand new to coding in Python, this is my first python code I've written. I'm coding a bot that will click a a web element via the xpath, I'm trying to make it go back to the original web page if the element is not there or if a different element is present
Here's a segment of the code

```
# Wait for the second web element to be clickable
        followbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button"))
        )
        followbutton.click()
```

However, sometimes the follow button has a slightly different xpath, and instead the Xpath is
`/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button` instead of

`"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button"`

How can I implement an if then statement so that if the xpath is this one:

`/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button`

then it does driver.back()

but if it's this one: `/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button`
then it does followbutton.click()?

I'm looking for any suggestions, Here's what the full segment of code looks like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Set the starting page number
page_num = 32

while True:
    # Navigate to the URL with the current page number
    url = f"https://urlhere.com/page={page_num}"
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(20)

    try:
        # Wait for the first web element to be clickable
        user1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div"))
        )
        user1.click()

        # Wait for 10 seconds
        time.sleep(10)

        # Wait for the second web element to be clickable
        followbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button"))
        )
        followbutton.click()

        time.sleep(3)
        driver.back()

        # Wait for 5 seconds
        time.sleep(5)
    # 2nd user
        user2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div"))
        )
        user2.click()
        time.sleep(2)
# 2nd users follow button
        followbutton2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button"))
        )
        followbutton2.click()
        driver.back()

    except:
        # If any exception occurs, break out of the loop
        break

    # Increment the page number
    page_num += 1

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Instead of using absolute XPATH, why don't you use relative XPATH. The latter will me more reliable and most likely will work even if the DOM structure change.

Comment: Check the answers in this link, this may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022658/selenium-python-handling-no-such-element-exception

Comment: Appreciate it, I don't know the difference between absolute XPATH and relative XPATH and don't know how to implement relative over absolute

Comment: This is a two parted question. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423699/should-two-part-questions-be-closed). Make sure your question fits the criteria of that answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all. Using such long absoulte paths is not a good idea if you want to build something reliable. You should further investigate if you can identify the element with a unique id or class.
2. If you really have an element that can be two different xpaths but does the same and can not appear twice. You can make an `union` in your xpath with the pipe `|`: For example:

```
//div/span/div|//div/span/span
```

3. If for some reason the elements are not available explore the `expected_conditions` methods. You have more elements like `EC.presence_of_element_located` or `EC.visibility_of_element_located` that may be useful if you also want to check that everything was loaded as expected. Specially if there are a lot of JS animations in the page.
4. If you really want to go the way of catching exceptions. Do not make a try except of everything. Catch only a specific exception. In this scenario if you are not able to find an element surround the search of the element with something like:

```py
try:
    followbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button"))
    )
    followbutton.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    # Handle what you want to happen here.
    ...
```

In general this is a too broad question. You have to investigate the DOM of the page and act accordingly in your code. There is no magic bullet for this.

Answer (score 0):

@nck's `union` solution is great and will definitely work, but it's also fun to look at what Selenium offers for solving problems like this.

Selenium allows you to [create custom wait conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20create%20custom%20wait%20conditions%20when%20none%20of%20the%20previous%20convenience%20methods%20fit%20your%20requirements.) to use with `WebDriverWait`. You can create a custom condition by creating a class with a `__call__` method that accepts the driver as an argument, and returns `False` when the condition isn't met and something [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) when the condition is met. Because the successful return value just has to be truth-*y*, we can customize the return type of our class to give us a little extra information:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class has_good_or_bad_element():
    def __init__(self, good_locator, bad_locator):
        self.good_locator = good_locator
        self.bad_locator = bad_locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            good_element = driver.find_element(*self.good_locator)
            return 'good', good_element
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            bad_element = driver.find_element(*self.bad_locator)
            return 'bad', bad_element
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        return False
```

Now we can call this like so:

```
element_type, element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    has_good_or_bad_element(
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button"), # selector for good element
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/header[1]/div/div[1]/aside[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button"), # selector for bad element
    )
)

if element_type == 'good':
    element.click()
else:
    driver.back()
```

Since you're new to python, there's some syntax here that you might be unfamiliar with. Here's some info on [returning multiple values](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-41-multiple-return-values-in-python/) (`return 'good', good_element`), [unpacking tuples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/) (`element_type, element = ...`), and [the `__init__` and `__call__` class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call).